# Display dates in a HTML table for each month with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

I'm trying to display dates in a HTML table. I want to display each month, but I failed when the dates go over a month for example: 2015-30-11 to 2015-01-12

They break the table because there are too many `<td>`'s and I don't know how to display them in the next month.

Each user Has their own dates.

[image]

Code:

```
$month = date(m);
$year  = date(Y);
$day   = date(d);


if (isset($_GET['month'])) {
    $month = $_GET['month'];
}

$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);


echo "<h2>$month-$day-$year</h2>";
echo "<h3>Amount of days: $days </h3>";
$days = $days + 1;

$employee_count = 0;
$sql            = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE inactive = 0";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Unable to execute query. ' . mysqli_error($con));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $employee_id[] = $row;
    $employee_count++;
}


echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tablehead>";
echo "<tr>";
for ($j = 0; $j < $days; $j++) {
    echo "<th>$j</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tablehead>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $employee_count; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";

    $id = $employee_id[$i]['employee_ID'];

    $sql    = "select * from employee where inactive = 0 and employee_ID = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $employee[] = $row;
    }

    $name    = $employee[0]['name'];
    $surname = $employee[0]['surname'];
    echo "<td>$surname $name</td>";

    $count_absences = 0;

    $sql    = "select * from absences where employee_FK = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $absences[] = $row;
        $count_absences++;
    }

    $table = $days - 1;
    $minus = 0;
    for ($l = 0; $l < $table; $l++) {


        for ($y = 0; $y < $count_absences; $y++) {
            $start       = $absences[$y]['start'];
            $end         = $absences[$y]['end'];
            $dStart      = new DateTime($start);
            $dEnd        = new DateTime($end);
            $dDiff       = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
            $diff        = $dDiff->days;
            $diff        = $diff + 1;
            $date        = $start;
            $start_day   = date('d', strtotime($date));
            $start_day   = $start_day - 1;
            $start_month = date('m', strtotime($date));
            $start_day   = $start_day - 1;

            if ($start_month == $month && $start_day == $l) {
                for ($a = 0; $a < $diff; $a++) {
                    echo "<td>X</td>";
                    $l++;
                }
            }

        }
        echo "<td></td>";


        unset($employee);
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    unset($absences);
}

echo "</table>";

if ($month == 12) {
    $next = 1;
} else {
    $next = $month + 1;
}

if ($month == 1) {
    $previous = 12;
} else {
    $previous = $month - 1;
}

echo "<br>";
echo "<button type=\"button\" name=\"previous\" ><a href=\"table_sev.php?month=$previous\">Previous</a></button>";
echo "<button type=\"button\" name=\"next\" ><a href=\"table_sev.php?month=$next\">Next</a></button>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise your inner loop like this:

```
 for($l=0;$l<$table;$l++){


    $mark = false;
    for($y=0; $y<$count_absences; $y++){
        $start =  $absences[$y]['start'];
        $end = $absences[$y]['end'];
        $dStart = new DateTime($start);
        $dEnd  = new DateTime($end);
        $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
        $diff = $dDiff->days + 1;     

        $start_day = date('d', strtotime($start)) - 1;
        $start_month = date('m', strtotime($start));

        $lString = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.($l+1);
        $lDate = new DateTime($lString);
        if($lDate>=$dStart && $lDate<=$dEnd){
            $mark = true;
            break;
        }
    }
   if($mark){
        echo "<td>X</td>";
    } else {
         echo "<td></td>";
    }



unset($employee);
}
```

That way on each iteration the specific day we're on for the employee will be checked against all date spans of their absence, even if absence spans across months.

Comment: Perfect solution, I think I tried to do this do but it got to messy

Answer (score 0):

I add this snippet:

```
        if ($start_month != $month) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
```

It might be all you need, but I am not sure if that is going to work.
In any case you need to check if you are in a different month to switch to next line. I am not sure where that would be in your code.

```
<?
$month = date(m);
$year  = date(Y);
$day   = date(d);


if (isset($_GET['month'])) {
    $month = $_GET['month'];
}

$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);


echo "<h2>$month-$day-$year</h2>";
echo "<h3>Amount of days: $days </h3>";
$days = $days + 1;

$employee_count = 0;
$sql            = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE inactive = 0";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Unable to execute query. ' . mysqli_error($con));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $employee_id[] = $row;
    $employee_count++;
}


echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tablehead>";
echo "<tr>";
for ($j = 0; $j < $days; $j++) {
    echo "<th>$j</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tablehead>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $employee_count; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";

    $id = $employee_id[$i]['employee_ID'];

    $sql    = "select * from employee where inactive = 0 and employee_ID = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $employee[] = $row;
    }

    $name    = $employee[0]['name'];
    $surname = $employee[0]['surname'];
    echo "<td>$surname $name</td>";

    $count_absences = 0;

    $sql    = "select * from absences where employee_FK = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $absences[] = $row;
        $count_absences++;
    }

    $table = $days - 1;
    $minus = 0;
    for ($l = 0; $l < $table; $l++) {


        for ($y = 0; $y < $count_absences; $y++) {
            $start       = $absences[$y]['start'];
            $end         = $absences[$y]['end'];
            $dStart      = new DateTime($start);
            $dEnd        = new DateTime($end);
            $dDiff       = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
            $diff        = $dDiff->days;
            $diff        = $diff + 1;
            $date        = $start;
            $start_day   = date('d', strtotime($date));
            $start_day   = $start_day - 1;
            $start_month = date('m', strtotime($date));
            $start_day   = $start_day - 1;
            if ($start_month != $month) {
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }
            if ($start_month == $month && $start_day == $l) {
                for ($a = 0; $a < $diff; $a++) {
                    echo "<td>X</td>";
                    $l++;
                }
            }

        }
        echo "<td></td>";


        unset($employee);
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    unset($absences);
}

echo "</table>";

if ($month == 12) {
    $next = 1;
} else {
    $next = $month + 1;
}

if ($month == 1) {
    $previous = 12;
} else {
    $previous = $month - 1;
}

echo "<br>";
echo "<button type=\"button\" name=\"previous\" ><a href=\"table_sev.php?month=$previous\">Previous</a></button>";
echo "<button type=\"button\" name=\"next\" ><a href=\"table_sev.php?month=$next\">Next</a></button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check in your loop that month of current date (in loop) is the same as month of previous date by keeping at the end of every loop the last value of month (`$actualMonth`). You probably have to setup this value outside the loop with null and ignore this verification if `$actualMonth` is null. Also, you can start verification after first loop.
If it's different, you have to `break` your loop. You can compare directly with your `$month` parameter.

OR

You could restrict your SQL query to get absence only for the month currently displayed.

MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE MONTH(date_to_checked) = month_number;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month